# How does Outlook identify (auto format) the company prefix in contact form?

Tags: outlook

Wondering how does outlook (any versions) identify the company name prefix in the contact form.

For example while creating a new contact in outlook, if I enter the company name as "The BestCompany", after tabbing out of that field it auto formats the company name as "BestCompany, The" and I believe "The" is considered or called as the company name prefix.

Want to know how does outlook identify what is the prefix? Noticed it's not always the first word of the company name because it doesn't do the same if we type in company name as "My BestCompany". So are there any predefined list of words it identifies as prefix?

Any clues in this regard is appreciated.